# In Python, how to do a grouped rolling average/standard deviation excluding current date and when dates are non-consecutive?

Tags: python, date, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I am rather new to Python (migrating from R) and working on some rolling average/rolling standard deviation data.

So I have a date column, a category column and a rate of change column.  For each date, I would like to get a rolling 10 days average of the rate of change data.  However I would like to exclude the current date in calculation.  And for my dates, they are not consecutive.

My dataframe looks like below,   [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdTyz.jpg)

and I am would like to create columns like below

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6DT7.jpg)

I really tried my best to glance through most questions here but cannot find exactly same question.  Some solution is to loop every row by using iterrow(), but my full dataset is around 70k entries and it is too slow to do so (maybe I write the code badly).

I also tried groupby rolling with shift.  But since the dates are non-consecutive, I find work it out too.

Here are some background for the study.  We need the rolling sum/mean/sd for decision making of next period.  However the last period data only comes after the next period started, that we have to exclude the current date data to remove look-ahead bias.  And the rate of change report does not comes daily, and each period not every items are reported.

My code in R is like this

df[,RollingMean := df[.(Item, Date , Date %m-% days(10)),on = .(Item = V1, Date < V2, Date >= V3), mean(Rate_of_Chg), by = .EACHI]$V1]

df$RollingMean <- df$RollingMean %>% replace_na(0)

Could I pick you guys brain on this?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach is to first impose a daily frequency (some days will have missing values) then use the rolling methods. To exclude the last date you can easily sort by the index (date) and use the .iloc method of pandas. For example:

```
# assume df is a pandas (pd) dataframe
# and Date is one of the columns

# 1. Set the index 
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

# 2. Make sure the index is datetime
df.index = df.index.map(pd.to_datetime) 

# 3. Resample to daily and sort it
df2 = df.resample('D').last().sort_index()

# 4. rolling method ex the last date
avg = df2.iloc[:-1].rolling(10).mean()
```

EDIT: added sort index and iloc to exclude the last date.